# Some code with linefill and I cannot understand why it does not behave as intended

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have written the following code to try to construct an indicator, but it seems not to behave as intended, and I don't fully understand why that is, perhaps I don't understand how linefill works or perhaps there is a reason that previous linefills are not being deleted as intended.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Fair Value Gap Indicator")

var float b1 = 0.0
var float b2 = 0.0
var bool flag = false
var bool previous_line = false
var line upper = na
var line lower = na

if (bar_index>3)
    if (close[2] < open[2])
        b1 := high[1]
        b2 := low[3]
        flag := (high[1] < low[3])
        if (flag)
            log.info("Found Fair Value Gap")
            if (previous_line)
                line.delete(upper)
                line.delete(lower)
                log.info("I deleted a pair of lines")
            upper := line.new(bar_index-2,b2,bar_index-1,b2,extend=extend.both)
            lower := line.new(bar_index-2,b1,bar_index-1,b1,extend=extend.both)
            previous_line := true
            linefill.new(upper,lower,color.red)
            log.info("Now there should be a red bar from "+str.tostring(b2)+" to "+str.tostring(b1))
    else
        b1 := low[1]
        b2 := high[3]
        flag := (low[1] > high[3])
        if (flag)
            log.info("Found Fair Value Gap")
            if (previous_line)
                line.delete(upper)
                line.delete(lower)
                log.info("I deleted a pair of lines")
            upper := line.new(bar_index-2, b1, bar_index-1, b1,extend=extend.both)
            lower := line.new(bar_index - 2, b2, bar_index-1,b2,extend=extend.both)
            previous_line := true
            linefill.new(upper,lower,color.green)
            log.info("Now there should be a green bar from "+str.tostring(b1)+" to "+str.tostring(b2))
```

The code should have a bar drawn between a pair of horizontal lines with y co-ordinates as given in the most recent Pine Log entry, but it doesn't seem to behave this way when tested against EUR/USD. I was wondering if anyone could help me work out what might be going wrong.

Comment: Howdy Rupert, I can not find any error with this code. It shows two lines only with the gab filled as green or red, and it deletes the old lines as expected. Maybe restart our browser or app, or clear the cache.

Comment: what you can do is using `linefill.delete()`, but again it is working without this command, cause you deleted those lines too.